# Is it possible to create a PHP function which can both display and return?

Tags: php, function, if-statement

Is it possible to create a PHP function which can both display and return (Only one thing per time according how I called it)? Please look at the example.

Ex:

```
public function test_function(){
    echo "Hello"; // echo or anything......
}
```

If I called it `test_function()` it should display "Hello";
If I use it like `$name = test_function();` `$name` should be equal to "Hello".

Note : **I know that passing another parameter and using if condition** I can do this. I am looking for more quick way if there is something like that.

Comment: No, that is not possible. Simply using `echo test_function();` when you want to output the result would be the simplest thing to do.

Comment: Just to note, "impossible" is a bit of a stretch. It's just harder / not worth it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. You should return 'Hello' and echo it if necessary.

```
function test_function() {
  return 'Hello';
}

$foo = test_function(); // $foo = 'Hello'
echo test_function(); // Prints 'Hello'
```

Answer (score 0):

No, what you're suggesting isn't possible. There are a few alternatives as you're already aware but you can't do both. If you attempt to `echo` and `return` in the same function, you're going to get unexpected results when you attempt to use the function in a return context.

The best solution would be to return a value in your function and then echo.

```
function test_function() {
    return 'Hello';
}

echo test_function();
```

Or

```
function test_function( $echo = false ) {
    $value = 'Hello';

    if ( $echo ) {
        echo $value;
    } else {
        return $value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's kinda possible with [ob_start](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php) and [ob_get_clean](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-clean.php), like so:

```
function test_function(){
    echo "Hello";
}

// Direct output
test_function();

echo PHP_EOL . '<br>-------<br>' . PHP_EOL;

// Catch output into variable
ob_start();
test_function();
$name = ob_get_clean();

echo "Name: " . $name;
```

Output:

> Hello 
>   ------- 
>   Name: Hello

See it running [here](https://3v4l.org/dTR0Z).

---

I feel like mentioning: the answers suggesting to always return the value and print when needed are probably the way to go.